# Sass Extend Works not like at Sassmeister

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I want this output which is delivered when I put my input into Sassmeister:

```
.brand-kampagne-klick, .brand-kampagne-klick-1 {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
.brand-kampagne-klick img, .brand-kampagne-klick-1 img {
  width: 100%;
}
.brand-kampagne-klick .beispiel-brand-kampagne, .brand-kampagne-klick-1 .beispiel-brand-kampagne {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.brand-kampagne-klick-1 .brand-kampagne-right {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

But instead my output is:

```
.brand-kampagne-klick, .brand-kampagne-klick-1 {
  margin-top: 3rem; }

  .brand-kampagne-klick img, .brand-kampagne-klick .brand-kampagne-klick-1 {
    width: 100%; }

  .brand-kampagne-klick .beispiel-brand-kampagne, .brand-kampagne-klick .brand-kampagne-klick-1 {
    margin-top: 3rem; }

.brand-kampagne-klick-1 .brand-kampagne-right {
  margin-top: 1rem; }
```

Because `.brand-kampagne-klick` is a pseudo class (I guess declaring with % doesnt work with extend) none of the styles is apllied.

My input is:

```
.brand-kampagne-klick {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .beispiel-brand-kampagne {
    margin-top: 3rem;
  }
}

.brand-kampagne-klick-1 {
  @extend .brand-kampagne-klick;
  .brand-kampagne-right {
    margin-top:1rem;
  }
}
```

Is there a difference between gulp-sass and sassmeister? I use `"gulp-sass": "~1.1.0",`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with any version of Sass offered by Sassmeister.  Also `.brand-kampagne-klick` is not a pseudo class.  The fact that you're using gulp-sass doesn't tell me anything about the Sass version that's running underneath (is it LibSass? The official Ruby Sass?  What version of those?)

Comment: I guess node-sass 3.3.0 https://www.versioneye.com/nodejs/gulp-sass/1.1.0